# Crossed fields : Finding the charge to mass ratio

Tags: electromagnetism

So, we are discussing the crossed field (JJ Thompson's) experiment in which the $q/m$ ratio of charged particles were produced.

Deflection due to the electric field is given by-
$$y=\frac{qEL^2}{2mv^2}$$

Now, if we adjust the $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ so that the net force is $0$ we get,$v=\frac{E}{B}$. Now, thus the crossed field can act as a *velocity selector*. Thus particles with velocity $E/B$ are undeflected as net force on them=$0$.

Now, my book says, we can substitute this value of $v$ in the previous equation to get-

$$\frac{m}{q}=\frac{B^2L^2}{2yE}$$

I don't understand how this works because $y$ would be $0$ when $v=E/B$. So, why don't we directly replace $y$ by $0$ in that equation. Shouldn't $y$ be $0$ when $v=E/B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experiment is in two parts.

With crossed electric (E) and magnetic (B) fields you adjust the electric field  and/or the magnetic field to get zero deflection from which you can find the spreed of the electrons.

Then the magnetic field is switched off and the deflection of the electrons $y$ due to only the electric field is measured from which the specific charge of the electron can be found using you second equation.